# Why doesn't my animation-direction:alternate work?

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: red 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: name;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes name {
  100% {
    transform: translate(400px, 300px);
    background-color: pink;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Hello , I thought my animation-direction:alternate is supposed be played forwards first then backwards. But it doesn't seem to work that way. Could someone explain me why?

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: I'm using Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

Consider `animation-iteration-count` with at least 2 as value to have such behavior

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: red 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: name;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count:2;
}

@keyframes name {
  100% {
    transform: translate(400px, 300px);
    background-color: pink;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

> The animation-iteration-count CSS property specifies **the number of**
>   **times an animation cycle should be played before stopping**. If multiple
>   values are specified, each time the animation is played the next value
>   in the list is used, cycling back to the first value after the last
>   one is used.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count)</sup>

---

> **alternate**
>
> The animation reverses direction **each cycle**, with the first
>   iteration being played forwards. The count to determine if a cycle is
>   even or odd starts at one.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction)</sup>

So your animation need to run more than once to have the alternate behavior.

Comment: he nedds this to support firefox:`-webkit-animation-direction`

Comment: @לבנימלכה no, the vendor prefix is no more needed ... he need to wait 6s until the animation is done ;)